# At which percentage of 2nd perk, perk reset leaves 1st perk at 100%?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I wanted to reset various perks of "value increases with progress" of my crew and replace them all with Brothers in Arms, which works only at 100%. I'm currently somewhere 25% up the 2nd perk but reset predicts leaving me with 98-99% of the 1st perk (paying credits (silver)), meaning incomplete BiA would be useless and I'd have to grind the last percent without perks whatsoever. How far do I have to grind 2nd perk to get 1st perk at 100% after "silver" reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a smidge over 210k skill/perk experience for a crew member to get to 100% on your 1st skill/perk.  The silver skill/perk reset has you losing 10% of your skill/perk XP, so you would need at least 233405 total skill/perk XP to keep the 100% in the first skill/perk.  You would achieve this at 41% on the 2nd skill/perk.

Math:
X*0.9 = 210064;
X = 233404.4 or about 23341XP into the second skill/perk.
[Used the crewXP calculator](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B2VEGT7EjCYONjdUSWxGTnhmVlk/edit?pli=1) to determine what % for the second skill would have at least that amount of skill/perk XP.

**Edit**: the crew calculator linked to above also has a section at the bottom for doing just this calculation (and I didn't know that until just now).  Using this, you can see that having a 41% for the 2nd skill/perk results in the 2nd skill/perk dropping to 1% after a silver reset.